# Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 127

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

```
|................................................................ |  98%
|.................................................................| 100%

output file: test.knit.md

/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --template /usr/lib64/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --variable 'theme:cerulean' --include-in-header /tmp/Rtmp4CjD4R/rmarkdown-str6f6421e357bc.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --highlight-style haddock 
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 127
```

Occasionally, I run the codes and it completed 100% and created a md format file.

```
> traceback()
10: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
9: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
8: lapply(aesthetics, eval, envir = data, enclos = plot$plot_env)
7: f(..., self = self)
6: l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
5: f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
4: by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
3: ggplot_build(x)
2: print.ggplot(x)
1: function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print")(x)
```

There is no ggplot function run inside the RMarkdown but there is ggplot error when I tried to traceback(). However there is an error Error:127, any solution?

[Googling the error message indicates that ‘status 127’ means that commands are not being found.](http://conjugateprior.org/2012/12/r-markdown-to-other-document-formats/)

Comment: please share a minimal example that reproduces the problem

Comment: [Betting Strategy and Model Validation.Rmd](https://github.com/Scibrokes/Betting-Strategy-and-Model-Validation/blob/master/Betting%20Strategy%20and%20Model%20Validation.Rmd), kindly shade me a light?

Comment: @RYOENG http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Comment: @RYOENG This is not *minimal*, nor *reproducible* (we need scripts and data that you are not sharing to use it). Please cut it down to the lines where your problem occurs, make sure everything needed to run it is in the script, and edit it in you question rather than on another website